# rsync from machine a to machine c

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have gentoo Linux.

I want to RSync to a remote machine that I need to SSH twice to get into.

how can I do that in one command ?

I used to do that with one command but I forgot how!

I used to do that without port forwarding.

I saved that ssh details in some file somehow but I forgot what exactly I did.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
rsync -avn /src -e "ssh user@intermidiate-host ssh" user@firewalled-host:/dst
```

Comment: wow.. that's not what i meant. that's way better.